# do you guys know any "leetcode" of maths?

Tags: real-analysis, contest-math, problem-solving

Math challenges like programming challenges but without the fact of programming anything.

I really want to sharpen my math skills with math problems, but i want to do it progressively cuz i've tried some problems and they're way too hard for me. I wanted to start from the very basic and start climbing up.

What do you guys suggest?

Please post only self-taught ways to learn, not interested in any academy or olimpyads

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123713/discussion-on-question-by-boomboom--do-you-guys-know-any-leetcode-of-m).